# How to store URL value in Mongoose Schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am uploading the images from an IOS application to Firebase which returns to me the metadata including the URL of type `URL`.

Should I store it of type `String` in the database like below code? or there is specific type for `URL`s?

```
var schema = new Schema({
  downloadURL: { type: String, createdDate: Date.now }
})
```

Answer (score 9):

Well, As per the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/schematypes.html) Monngoose doesn't have a schema type for URL. You could just use a string with RegExp to validate it or use some custome made type like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-type-url)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('mongoose-type-url');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
url: {
    work: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Url,
    profile: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Url
}
});
```

Comment: what if someone is using 'ES module' instead of 'commonjs' ?

Answer (score 7):

Mongoose does not have schema for URL, you can store in String and Validate using [mongoose-Validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-validator)

Here is the syntax for it

```
validate: { 
  validator: value => validator.isURL(value, { protocols: ['http','https','ftp'], require_tld: true, require_protocol: true }),
  message: 'Must be a Valid URL' 
}
```

Hope this will Help you

Answer (score 7):

You can use Regex to Validate the URL like this,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    downloadURL: {
        type: String,
        required: 'URL can\'t be empty',
        unique: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Description can\'t be empty',
    }
});

userSchema.path('downloadURL').validate((val) => {
    urlRegex = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-/]))?/;
    return urlRegex.test(val);
}, 'Invalid URL.');
```